# PHP WYSIWYG Editor Body Tag Empty Checker

Tags: php, html, editor, character

I'm using TinyMCE editor with fullpage plugin. If I check form field for empty, it's always returned true, because automatically added HTML fullpage codes like;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I check this field only between body tags? Except **if(str_len($field)<61)**

Comment: simply use a string compare

Comment: regexp better i guess, I wanna use this on a cms project, if user wanna change document type, static content checker will not work.

Comment: added regular expression option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i do this for ckeditor, same kind of thing

```
if ($_POST['foo']=="<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>"){
echo 'its empty';
}
```

you could get fancy with a regular expression checking what's between `<body>` and `</body>` but  that's overkill

---

regular expression option

```
preg_match('/<body>(\s*)<\/body>/s', $_POST['foo'], $matches);

//var_dump($matches);

if(isset($matches[1])){
echo 'empty';   
}
```